# Issue adding Bootstrap on Ruby on Rails Project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bootstrap-4

[This](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-rubygem) is what I followed in order to get started with bootstrap on Ruby on Rails.

I followed every step exactly the same. However, I keep running into the same error for some reason. When I do not do any thing (i.e. do not use bootstrap) everything works (but the application looks trashy).
Whenever I use bootstrap, I get:

```
invalid regexp character
```

This is the application trace:

```
(execjs):24299
app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:8:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__337612969_59863020'
```

I have no clue what is happening.

**P.S.** I am a beginner. So if the solution is simple then, yeah...

Comment: Can you post your application.html.erb file? It be good to see what it looks like at, and around, line 8.

Comment: <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>

This is line 8 @MrDanA... :(

Comment: Okay, can you post your application stylesheet?

Comment: I renamed it to application.scss
Removed everything from it and just placed @import "bootstrap";

Answer (score 0):

remove #gem 'duktape' from gem file..the issue will be solved